# How to split a dataframe based on similarity of rows?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
            0      1       2       3
xxx_qsaqx   2      2.2    2.3      2.4
xxx_gtygs   3      3.2    3.3      3.4
xxx_uytgo   4      4.2    4.3      4.4
xxx_ytghr   5      5.2    5.3      5.4
xxy_uyhga   6      6.2    6.3      6.4
xxy-uytei   7      7.2    7.3      7.4
xyy_uiyta   8      8.2    8.3      8.4
```

And I want to split it into the following 3 dataframes:

xxx-df

```
            0      1       2       3
xxx_qsaqx   2      2.2    2.3      2.4
xxx_gtygs   3      3.2    3.3      3.4
xxx_uytgo   4      4.2    4.3      4.4
xxx_ytghr   5      5.2    5.3      5.4
```

xxy-df

```
            0      1       2       3
xxy_uyhga   6      6.2    6.3      6.4
xxy-uytei   7      7.2    7.3      7.4
```

xyy-df

```
            0      1       2       3
xyy_uiyta   8      8.2    8.3      8.4
```

**Note that strings are indeed the row indices while 0, 1, 2, and 3 are the columns of the dataframes.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to generate variables dynamically, [this is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables).

Instead, collect the DataFrames in a dictionary using a combination of [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the prefix and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to split the groups:

```
grouper = df.index.str.extract('^([^-_]+)', expand=False)

dfs = {k: g for k,g in df.groupby(grouper)}
```

Output:

```
{'xxx':            0    1    2    3
        xxx_qsaqx  2  2.2  2.3  2.4
        xxx_gtygs  3  3.2  3.3  3.4
        xxx_uytgo  4  4.2  4.3  4.4
        xxx_ytghr  5  5.2  5.3  5.4,
 'xxy':            0    1    2    3
        xxy_uyhga  6  6.2  6.3  6.4
        xxy-uytei  7  7.2  7.3  7.4,
 'xyy':            0    1    2    3
        xyy_uiyta  8  8.2  8.3  8.4,
}
```

And access your sub-DataFrames with:

```
dfs['xxx']

           0    1    2    3
xxx_qsaqx  2  2.2  2.3  2.4
xxx_gtygs  3  3.2  3.3  3.4
xxx_uytgo  4  4.2  4.3  4.4
xxx_ytghr  5  5.2  5.3  5.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                   1: [2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2, 7.2, 8.2],
                   2: [2.3, 3.3, 4.3, 5.3, 6.3, 7.3, 8.3],
                   3: [2.4, 3.4, 4.4, 5.4, 6.4, 7.4, 8.4]},
                  index=['xxx_qsaqx', 'xxx_gtygs', 'xxx_uytgo',
                         'xxx_ytghr', 'xxy_uyhga', 'xxy-uytei', 'xyy_uiyta'],
                  )


xxx_df, xxy_df, xyy_df = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df.index.str[:3])]
```

Output xxx_df:

```
            0   1   2   3   
xxx_qsaqx   2   2.2 2.3 2.4 
xxx_gtygs   3   3.2 3.3 3.4 
xxx_uytgo   4   4.2 4.3 4.4
xxx_ytghr   5   5.2 5.3 5.4
```

Output xxy_df:

```
            0   1   2   3
xxy_uyhga   6   6.2 6.3 6.4 
xxy-uytei   7   7.2 7.3 7.4
```

Output xyy_df:

```
            0   1   2   3   
xyy_uiyta   8   8.2 8.3 8.4
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
for key, df in df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0]):
    globals()[key + '_df'] = df
```

---

chk variables

```
print(xxx_df)
```

output:

```
            0   1   2   3
xxx_qsaqx   2   2.2 2.3 2.4
xxx_gtygs   3   3.2 3.3 3.4
xxx_uytgo   4   4.2 4.3 4.4
xxx_ytghr   5   5.2 5.3 5.4
```